# How can I redirect a user to an unauthorised page based the result of an async call from stateChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

I would like a central place to check if a user is authorised to navigate to states in my application (e.g. can current user view details page for company x). Adding a line to every resolver seems a bit messy so I was looking into using the `stateChangeStart` event provided by [`[ui-router]`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference) to navigate to an unauthorised state if the server says the user is not authorised to navigate to that state.

This is sort of a "soft check" before the `resolve` function fires for a state to get the required data for the page for real (which is also secured).

So for states relating to companies, I have an endpoint I use which returns a boolean:

`/authorisationCheck?type=company&companyId=5&accessLevel=view`

The bare bones looks something like this:

```
angular
    .module('app', [...])
    .controller('appController', function($rootScope){...})
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){...})
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

            switch(toState.name) {
                case 'company.index':
                case 'company.details':

                    // user requires "view" permission for a company so check on the server
                    // I want this block to complete before the resolve function runs in the state being navigated to
                    Restangular.one('authorisationCheck')
                    .get({ type: 'company', companyId: toParams.companyId, accessLevel: "view" })
                    .then(function(result) {

                        if(!result.allowAccess) {
                            event.preventDefault(); // documented in ui-router to prevent transition
                            state.transitionTo('error.unauthorised');
                        }

                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        });
    });
```

My problem is that this check is using restangular and therefore asynchronous, so while I'm doing my access check the resolve function in the `toState` is firing. I would like to block execution to the `resolve` function until the access check has been performed. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://gist.github.com/thomasnordlund/4025773) or [this](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/)

Answer (score 0):

I think @caleb has almost answered what you are looking for in the comment above, but one think i also found useful while in a situation like this is to ask for an elevated privilege before rejecting the request so that someone does not have to search for the path again, much like in windows 7 where it throws up a password dialog to check if I do have a right access. its also useful when someone is trying to access the deep linking url that needs login.

to cut the story short, you could also look at the [following link](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) as it lets the call to to proceed to the requested path once authenticated.